# Put the serialization of a class into a DLL

Tags: c++, dll, boost-serialization

I'm looking for a (working) example for externally serializing a class-structure in a DLL. Currently I'm not able to find any examples for that. The Boost documentation is just stating some macros, the forums and newsgroups are just discussing specific problems with their solutions.

So I'm asking for an example for (externally) serializing a class-structure like the following. Along with the class-code I added some code of mine for serializing (which does not work, see bottom for error-message).

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() { number_ = 0; }
    virtual ~Foo() {}

    int getNumber() { return number_; }
    void setNumber( int var ) { number_ = var; }
private:
    int number_;
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    Bar() { doubleNumber_ = 0.0; }
    virtual ~Bar() {}

    double getDouble() { return doubleNumber_; }
    void setDouble( double var ) { doubleNumber_ = var; }

private:
    double doubleNumber_;
};
```

All what I've got so far is code like this:

**serializeFoo.h**

```
#ifndef _SERIALIZE_FOO_H_
#define _SERIALIZE_FOO_H_

#include "Foo.h"
#include <boost/serialization/split_free.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/version.hpp>

namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

template <typename Archive>
void save(Archive& ar, const Foo& object, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar << object.getNumber();
}

template <typename Archive>
void load(Archive& ar, Foo& object, const unsigned int version)
{
    int number;
    ar >> number;
    object.setNumber(number);
}

}} //namespace brackets

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE( Foo )

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY( Foo )

#endif //_SERIALIZE_FOO_H_
```

**serializeFoo.cpp**

```
#include "serializeFoo.h"
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT( Foo )
```

**serializeBar.h**:

```
#ifndef _SERIALIZE_BAR_H_
#define _SERIALIZE_BAR_H_

#include "Bar.h"
#include <boost/serialization/split_free.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/version.hpp>

namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

template <typename Archive>
void save(Archive& ar, const Bar& object, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar << base_object<Foo>(object);
    ar << object.getDouble();
}

template <typename Archive>
void load(Archive& ar, Bar& object, const unsigned int version)
{
    double doubleNumber;
    ar >> doubleNumber;
    object.setDouble(doubleNumber);
}

}} //namespace brackets

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE( Bar )

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY( Bar )

#endif //_SERIALIZE_BAR_H_
```

**serializeBar.cpp**:

```
#include "serializeBar.h"
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT( Bar )
```

The serialization-code goes into a DLL and should be used in another project using classes Foo and Bar. Everything compiles fine, but at runtime I get the message
`unregistered class - derived class not registered or exported`

So did I used the wrong macros? Do I miss a macro? Is the above code right or is there some kind of structural error? Perhaps this could be useful for a lot of other people too, I don't think that putting the serialization of a class into a DLL is very exotic...

Comment: On thing I saw on the Boost-docs was `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_FACTORY_0(Foo)`, but I do not know if it is needed and if I should use it. Link: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#dlls

Comment: Well, if it makes you feel any better, I have a project in which it's working just fine, and the code looks pretty identical to what you have, except for the fact that I include the archive headers at the top of the header file. P.S. it's technically a `.so`, not a `.dll`, shouldn't make a difference though...

Comment: You're right, I meant to write "Shared lib" at first, but wrote DLL because I wanted to show that it is currently a problem with this specific type of shared lib.

Comment: Just a notice, the doc you linked to is for v1.37, the current version is 1.48. You **might** be looking at the wrong doc to begin with... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue recently, 3 years after this question was asked. I finally found out a workaround to solve it. In the example above.

- `Bar` is a subclass of `Foo`, so it must be registered/exported;
- `serializeFoo.cpp` instantiates a GUID template class to register/export `Foo`;
- `serializeBar.cpp` instantiates a GUID template class to register/export `Bar`;
- The rules to include all necessary archive types before exporting the class keys are respected;
- Both translation units are linked together to create a DLL.

I assume in your exe, while you are trying to serialise a `Foo*` pointer pointing to a `Bar` object, you got the "unregistered class blahblah" error. This is because Boost.Serialization somehow does not properly generate a GUID for class `Bar` **before** the serialize function is called.

I don't know why this happens, but it seems that GUID is generated in a lazy way -- if none of the symbols from the translation unit `serializeBar.cpp` is used, none of the instantiation/initialization code defined in that translation unit will be performed -- that includes the class registration/exportation of `Bar`.

To prove that, you can try to use a (dummy) symbol in `serializeBar.cpp` (e.g. by calling a dummy function implemented in `serializeBar.cpp`) before calling any serialization function for `Foo*`. The issue should disappear.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

the test suite and demo distributed with the serialization library demonstrate exactly this facility. So first make sure that works. Then compare your example to it.

Robert Ramey

"Honestly, IMHO, at some points, Boost Serialization crosses the border of what is reliably possible with pure c++ build model w/o external tools..."

hmmmmmm - so it crosses the boarder as what's possible?  You're pretty much correct in spirit though.  Great effort was expended to implement everything that was considered necessary for such a package to be acceptable into boost.

RR

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell... There are many chances for things to go wrong. I recommend to download the test code for boost serialization (www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/test/). Have a look at the test cases around A.h, A.cpp and dll_a.cpp (which basically test your scenario) and try to make it work outside of the boost test system: use your build environment, try to modify compiler/linker options to match those of boost test suite for your toolset.

Honestly,  IMHO, at some points, Boost Serialization crosses the border of what is reliably possible with pure c++ build model w/o external tools...

Answer (score 0):

Use `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` to register all your classes which you would like to serialize