# Serialization of a derived nested class defined inside of a dll

Tags: c++, dll, derived-class, boost-serialization

Since many days I'm trying to solve dll-serialization-problem of a derived nested class. I've tried out a lot of examples I've found ( i.e [export_keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189055/put-the-serialization-of-a-class-into-a-dll)), but I allways get runtime error. There is some problems with access to serialization functions. I've wrote a simplified class similar to classes we use according to [boost serialization tests (polymorphic_derived2)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/test/).

// #############  dll  ###################

// PlugInClass_Derived_2.h //

```
#pragma once

#ifdef PLUGIN
// All functions in this file are exported
#else
// All functions in this file are imported
#define PLUGIN __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include "PlugInClass_Derived_1.h"

class PlugInClass_Derived_2 : public PlugInClass_Derived_1
{
public:

    class DLL_DECL(BOOST_PP_EMPTY()) Parameter : public PlugInClass_Derived_1::Parameter
    {
    public:

        Parameter(void);
        virtual ~Parameter(void){};

    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;

        template <typename Archive>
        void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version);

    public:
        virtual const char * get_key() const {
            return "PlugInClass_Derived_2_Parameter";
        }
    };

public:

    /** @brief  standard constructor */
    PlugInClass_Derived_2(){};
    virtual ~PlugInClass_Derived_2(){};

    PLUGIN virtual boost::shared_ptr<PlugInClass_Base::Parameter> getInitParameter();
};



extern "C" PLUGIN PlugInClass_Base* Create(/*void** params, const int number*/);
extern "C" PLUGIN void Destroy(PlugInClass_Base* p);

// we use this because we want to assign a key to this type
// but we don't want to explicitly instantiate code every time
// we do so!!!.  If we don't do this, we end up with the same
// code in BOTH the DLL which implements polymorphic_derived2
// as well as the main program.
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(PlugInClass_Derived_2::Parameter)

// note the mixing of type_info systems is supported.
BOOST_CLASS_TYPE_INFO(
PlugInClass_Derived_2::Parameter,
boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<PlugInClass_Derived_2::Parameter>
)

#undef DLL_DECL
```

// PlugInClass_Derived_2.cpp

```
/* boost headers go here */

/* plugin headers go here */
#define POLYMORPHIC_DERIVED2_EXPORT
#include "PlugInClass_Derived_2.h"

PlugInClass_Derived_2::Parameter::Parameter(){
    d = -2.;
    /*nothing*/
}

template <typename Archive>
void PlugInClass_Derived_2::Parameter::serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<PlugInClass_Derived_1::Parameter>(*this);
}

boost::shared_ptr<PlugInClass_Base::Parameter> PlugInClass_Derived_2::getInitParameter(){
    // get local data pointer;
    boost::shared_ptr<PlugInClass_Base::Parameter> localParameter(new  PlugInClass_Derived_2::Parameter());
    // update parent information

    // return local data
    return localParameter;
}


PlugInClass_Base* Create(/*void** params, const int number*/) {
    return new PlugInClass_Derived_2();
}


void Destroy(PlugInClass_Base* p) {
    delete p;
}



// instantiate code for text archives
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

template EXPORT_DECL(void) PlugInClass_Derived_2::Parameter::serialize(
    boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar,
    const unsigned int version
    );
template EXPORT_DECL(void) PlugInClass_Derived_2::Parameter::serialize(
    boost::archive::text_iarchive & ar,
    const unsigned int version
    );

// instantiate code for polymorphic archives
#include <boost/archive/polymorphic_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/polymorphic_oarchive.hpp>

template EXPORT_DECL(void) PlugInClass_Derived_2::Parameter::serialize(
    boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive & ar,
    const unsigned int version
    );
template EXPORT_DECL(void) PlugInClass_Derived_2::Parameter::serialize(
    boost::archive::polymorphic_iarchive & ar,
    const unsigned int version
    );


// MWerks users can do this to make their code work
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_MWERKS_BASE_AND_DERIVED(
    PlugInClass_Derived_1::Parameter
    , PlugInClass_Derived_2::Parameter)

    // note: export has to be AFTER #includes for all archive classes
    BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(PlugInClass_Derived_2::Parameter)
```

// PlugInClass_Derived_1.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef PLUGIN
// All functions in this file are exported
#else
// All functions in this file are imported
#define PLUGIN __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include "PlugInClass_Base.h"

class PlugInClass_Derived_1 : public PlugInClass_Base
{
public:

    class DLL_DECL(BOOST_PP_EMPTY()) Parameter : public PlugInClass_Base::Parameter
    {
    public:

        int a, b, c;

        Parameter(void);
        virtual ~Parameter(void){};

    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;

        template <typename Archive>
        void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version);

    public:
        virtual const char * get_key() const {
            return "PlugInClass_Derived_1_Parameter";
        }
    };

public:

    /** @brief  standard constructor */
    PlugInClass_Derived_1(){};
    virtual ~PlugInClass_Derived_1(){};

    virtual boost::shared_ptr<PlugInClass_Base::Parameter> getInitParameter();
};


// we use this because we want to assign a key to this type
// but we don't want to explicitly instantiate code every time
// we do so!!!.  If we don't do this, we end up with the same
// code in BOTH the DLL which implements polymorphic_derived2
// as well as the main program.
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(PlugInClass_Derived_1::Parameter)

// note the mixing of type_info systems is supported.
BOOST_CLASS_TYPE_INFO(
PlugInClass_Derived_1::Parameter,
boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<PlugInClass_Derived_1::Parameter>
)
```

// PlugInClass_Derived_1.cpp

```
/* boost headers go here */

/* plugin headers go here */
#define POLYMORPHIC_DERIVED2_EXPORT
#include "PlugInClass_Derived_1.h"

PlugInClass_Derived_1::Parameter::Parameter():
a(1),
b(2),
c(3)
{
    d = -1.;
    /*nothing*/
}

template <typename Archive>
void PlugInClass_Derived_1::Parameter::serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<PlugInClass_Base::Parameter>(*this);
    ar & a;
    ar & b;
    ar & c;

}

boost::shared_ptr<PlugInClass_Base::Parameter> PlugInClass_Derived_1::getInitParameter(){
    // get local data pointer;
    boost::shared_ptr<PlugInClass_Base::Parameter> localParameter(new  PlugInClass_Derived_1::Parameter());
    // update parent information

    // return local data
    return localParameter;
}


// instantiate code for text archives
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

template EXPORT_DECL(void) PlugInClass_Derived_1::Parameter::serialize(
    boost::archive::text_oarchive & ar,
    const unsigned int version
    );
template EXPORT_DECL(void) PlugInClass_Derived_1::Parameter::serialize(
    boost::archive::text_iarchive & ar,
    const unsigned int version
    );

// instantiate code for polymorphic archives
#include <boost/archive/polymorphic_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/polymorphic_oarchive.hpp>

template EXPORT_DECL(void) PlugInClass_Derived_1::Parameter::serialize(
    boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive & ar,
    const unsigned int version
    );
template EXPORT_DECL(void) PlugInClass_Derived_1::Parameter::serialize(
    boost::archive::polymorphic_iarchive & ar,
    const unsigned int version
    );


// MWerks users can do this to make their code work
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_MWERKS_BASE_AND_DERIVED(
    PlugInClass_Base::Parameter
    , PlugInClass_Derived_1::Parameter)

    // note: export has to be AFTER #includes for all archive classes
    BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(PlugInClass_Derived_1::Parameter)
```

// PlugInClass_Base.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef PLUGIN
// All functions in this file are exported
#else
// All functions in this file are imported
#define PLUGIN __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// boost headers
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/assume_abstract.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/tracking.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/type_info_implementation.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/extended_type_info_no_rtti.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp>

#include <boost/preprocessor/empty.hpp>

// export_decl, import_decl from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/test/
#ifdef BOOST_HAS_DECLSPEC // defined in config system
#if ! defined(EXPORT_DECL)
#if defined(__BORLANDC__)
#define EXPORT_DECL(T)  T __export
#else
#define EXPORT_DECL(T) __declspec(dllexport) T 
#endif
#endif
#if ! defined(IMPORT_DECL)
#if defined(__BORLANDC__)
#define IMPORT_DECL(T)    T __import
#else
#define IMPORT_DECL(T)    __declspec(dllimport) T 
#endif
#endif
#else
#define IMPORT_DECL(T) T
#define EXPORT_DECL(T) T
#endif // BOOST_HAS_DECLSPEC

#if defined(POLYMORPHIC_DERIVED_IMPORT)
#define DLL_DECL IMPORT_DECL
#elif defined(POLYMORPHIC_DERIVED_EXPORT)
#define DLL_DECL EXPORT_DECL
#else
#define DLL_DECL(x)
#endif

class PlugInClass_Base
{
public:

    class DLL_DECL(BOOST_PP_EMPTY()) Parameter
    {
    public:

        double d;

        virtual ~Parameter(void){};

    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;

        template <typename Archive>
        void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version){
            ar & d;
        };

    public:
        virtual const char * get_key() const = 0;
    };

public:

    /** @brief  standard constructor */
    PlugInClass_Base(){};
    virtual ~PlugInClass_Base(){};

    PLUGIN virtual boost::shared_ptr<PlugInClass_Base::Parameter> getInitParameter(){return NULL;};
};

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(PlugInClass_Base::Parameter)

// we use this because we want to assign a key to this type
// but we don't want to explicitly instantiate code every time
// we do so!!!.  If we don't do this, we end up with the same
// code in BOTH the DLL which implements polymorphic_derived2
// as well as the main program.
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(PlugInClass_Base::Parameter)

// note the mixing of type_info systems is supported.
BOOST_CLASS_TYPE_INFO(
PlugInClass_Base::Parameter,
boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<PlugInClass_Base::Parameter>
)
```

/// ######### end of dll ################### ///

// and at least the main

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/assume_abstract.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/tracking.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/type_info_implementation.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/extended_type_info_no_rtti.hpp>

#include "PlugIn_Derived\PlugInClass_Base.h"

#include <windows.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    boost::shared_ptr<PlugInClass_Base> dll_;

    /// ######### load dll ################### ///
    std::string pluginPath_ = "PlugInClass_Derived_2.dll";

    HINSTANCE currLibrary = LoadLibrary(pluginPath_.c_str());

    if (!currLibrary) {
        throw std::runtime_error("The plugin could not be loaded.");
    }

    // load the plugin class interface from the library using its factory functions
    typedef PlugInClass_Base *(*CreatePluginFuncDef)();
    CreatePluginFuncDef pluginCreateFactoryPtr = (CreatePluginFuncDef)GetProcAddress(currLibrary, "Create");
    typedef void(*DestroyPluginFuncDef)(PlugInClass_Base*);
    DestroyPluginFuncDef pluginDestroyPtr = (DestroyPluginFuncDef)GetProcAddress(currLibrary, "Destroy");
    // create object within dll
    dll_ = boost::shared_ptr<PlugInClass_Base>(pluginCreateFactoryPtr(), pluginDestroyPtr);

    /// ######### get object from dll ################### ///
    boost::shared_ptr<PlugInClass_Base::Parameter> parameterPtr = dll_->getInitParameter();

    /// ######### serialization ################### ///
    std::string s;
    // create and open a character archive for output
    {
        std::ostringstream os;
        // save data to archive
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(os);

        // write class instance to archive
        oa << parameterPtr; // HERE RUNTIME ERROR
        // Unhandled exception at xxxx in test_dll_simple_example.exe: 
        // Microsoft C++ exception: boost::archive::archive_exception at memory location xxxx

        s = os.str();
    }

    // ... some time later restore the class instance to its orginal state

    std::system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see the class I want so serialize is allways a nested class "Parameter" defined in derived class from "dll"-interface (PlugInClass_Base) and derived from parameter class of base class (i.e PlugInClass_Derived_1::Parameter). The dll-function "getInitParameter" returns the base pointer to the base-class of parameter-class we want to store.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong during the serialization? I would be glad if you can give me some hints.

Alexandros.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out, if the base-pointer is casted to derived pointer, the serialization works.

```
    /// ######### get object from dll ################### ///
    boost::shared_ptr<PlugInClass_Base::Parameter> parameterPtr = dll_->getInitParameter();
    boost::shared_ptr<PlugInClass_Derived_2::Parameter> derivedParameterPtr = boost::static_pointer_cast<PlugInClass_Derived_2::Parameter>(parameterPtr);

    /// ######### serialization ################### ///
    std::string s;
    // create and open a character archive for output
    {
        std::ostringstream os;
        // save data to archive
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(os);

        oa << derivedParameterPtr; // It works !!!

        s = os.str();
    }
```

So, somehow the serialization can't go through all derived pointers in the base pointer. 
The base-class is a abstact class

```
(BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(PlugInClass_Base::Parameter))
```

and the keys are exported

```
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(PlugInClass_Base::Parameter)
```

and there is implementation of each derived class is exported ( in cpp file )

```
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(PlugInClass_Derived_1::Parameter)
```

Can it be a problem with keys of nested classes ? Otherwise all derived classes have their own get_key() function.

Any assumptions ?

Answer (score 0):

The last post is wrong.
It works, because for casting of base pointer the derived class has to be linked -> static.

It means dll-serialization still not works